# Update primefaces datatable content from client side

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to change the content of a primefaces datatable on the client side using jQuery(adding rows,updating cells ...).

The problem is that I will need to have the model updated on the server side.

So my question is is there a way to make the server side aware of the changes made on the client side ?

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: What are these model's changes in the client side ?

Comment: if you have to make changes on the server-side, why don't you make the changes directly on the server-side, then simply update the client side?

Comment: because i'm using google for the geocoding and I must do it on the client-side because there will be a limit on the number of requests of geocoding..

Comment: You can try with `<p:remoteCommand>` and when you add row in jQuery then invoke in this function as well  `<p:remoteCommand>` which will call backing bean method when you update model on the server side.

Comment: Please explain the core issue for which you think your question is the solution. Your comment _"because i'm using google for the geocoding and I must do it on the client-side because there will be a limit on the number of requests of geocoding"_ does not make it any clearer. It might indeed be that sending the result of the geocoding to the server via a `p:remoteCommand` as Geinmachi proposes and do the updating there is the way to go. But again, that depends on the actual problem